# Turn a group of while loops into one big one

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

how would I turn this set of while loops into one big while loop with each of these tests to validate the username? Any help would be appreciated!

```
username = input("Please enter a username: ")


while len(username) < 8 or len(username) > 15:
    print("Username must be between 8 and 15 characters long.")
    username = input("Please enter a username: ")
while username.isalpha() == False:
    print ("Username can only contain alphanumeric characters.")
    username = input("Please enter a username: ")
while username.islower() == False:
    print ("Usernames must contain at least one lowercase character")
    username = input("Please enter a username: ")
while username.isupper() == False:
    print ("Usernames must contain at least one uppercase character")
    username = input("Please enter a username: ")
while username.isnumeric() == False:
    print ("Usernames must contain at least one numeric character")
    username = input("Please enter a username: ")
    firstch = username([0])
    lastch = username([-1])
while firstch.isnumeric == True:
    print ("The first character in a username cannot be a digit")
    username = input("Please enter a username: ")
while lastch.isnumeric == True:
    print ("The last character in a username cannot be a digit")
    username = input("Please enter a username: ")
    break
```

Comment: The OP need to output the error messages, so `and`-ing all the conditions won't be satisfactory.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're completely intent on warning for every single check (I'd probably just validate it, then display the rules in one go) you can use something like:

```
from unicodedata import category

username = input('Please enter a username: ')

valid = bool(
    # Length check
    8 <= len(username) <= 15
    # No digits for first or last character 
    and not username[0].isdigit() 
    and not username[-1].isdigit() 
    # Consists of only uppercase, lowercase or digits - but at least one of each
    and {'Lu', 'Ll', 'Nd'} == {category(ch) for ch in username}
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the whole input process into one `while` loop and check the conditions using single `if` statements:

```
username_is_valid = False

while not username_is_valid:

    username = input("Please enter a username: ")

    if len(username) < 8 or len(username) > 15:
        print("Username must be between 8 and 15 characters long.")
        continue
    if not username.isalpha():
        print ("Username can only contain alphanumeric characters.")
        continue
    if not username.islower():
        print ("Usernames must contain at least one lowercase character")
        continue
    if not username.isupper():
        print ("Usernames must contain at least one uppercase character")
        continue
    if not username.isnumeric():
        print ("Usernames must contain at least one numeric character")
        continue

    firstch = username([0])
    lastch = username([-1])

    if firstch.isnumeric:
        print ("The first character in a username cannot be a digit")
        continue
    if lastch.isnumeric:
        print ("The last character in a username cannot be a digit")
        continue

    break

print("Username is valid!")
```

**Edit:**

I see that some of your conditions are wrong. For example:

`username.islower()` and `username.isupper()` can never be true for the same input. Have a look at @John's answer for a solution.

And as @zondo mentioned you can also simplify your boolean checks (please compare your conditions with mine)

Comment: Don't use `... == False`  Use `not ...`

Comment: While I agree with the `... == False` part (which I BTW just copy&pasted from the OP) I can't see what's wrong with the `not ...` part. Could you please explain?

Comment: I'm trying to recommend the `not ...`  That's what I think you should use.

Comment: And `...  ==  True` is redundant, isn't?

Comment: I think the upper/lower tests should be `if not any(c.islower() for c in username):`

Answer (score 2):

```
checks = [
    (lambda: 8 <= len (username) <= 15, 'Username must be between 8 and 15 characters long.'),
    (lambda: username.isalpha (), 'Username can only contain alphanumeric characters.'),
    # And so on, you get the idea, it is very simple to expand this list and you can even make it dynamic.
]

while True:
    username = input ('Please enter a username: ')
    for check in checks:
        if not check [0] ():
            print (check [1])
            break
    else:
        break
```

Comment: OK, the else clause is only done if the break isn't.

Answer (score 1):

A much more sane way to structure this in my opinion is

```
username_is_valid = False

while not username_is_valid:
    username = input("Please enter a username: ")
    if len(username) < 8 or len(username) > 15:
        print("Username must be between 8 and 15 characters long.")
    elif username.isalpha() == False:
        print ("Username can only contain alphanumeric characters.")
    else:
        username_is_valid = True
```

also some of your logic isn't going to work the way you want it to for instance `username.isupper()` should be written as

```
import string
if not any(c in username for c in string.ascii_uppercase):
    print("username needs one uppercase character")
```

Here's a more complete solution

```
username_is_valid = False

while not username_is_valid:
    username = input("Please enter a username: ")
    if len(username) < 8 or len(username) > 15:
        print("Username must be between 8 and 15 characters long.")
    elif not username.isalnum():
        print("Username can only contain alphanumeric characters.")
    elif not any(c.islower() for c in username):
        print("Usernames must contain at least one lowercase character")
    elif not any(c.isupper() for c in username):
        print("Usernames must contain at least one uppercase character")
    elif not any(c.isdigit() for c in username):
        print("Usernames must contain at least one numeric character")
    elif username[0].isdigit():
        print("The first character in a username cannot be a digit")
    elif username[-1].isdigit():
        print("The last character in a username cannot be a digit")
    else:
        username_is_valid = True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_len(name):
    return (len(name) >= 8) and (len(name) <= 15)

conds = [check_len, str.isalpha, str.islower, ...] #conditions for the name in general
msgs = ["Username must be between 8 and 15 characters long.", \
        "Username can only contain alphanumeric characters.", \
        ...]  #corresponding error messages

parsed = False
while True:
    uname = input('Please enter username: ')
    for i in range(len(conds)):
        func = conds[i]  
        if not func(uname):  # call each function on the username
            print(msgs[i])   # print the corresponding err msg
            break
    else:
        parsed = True  # initial checks are done

    if not parsed:   # else restart the loop
        continue

    if uname[0].isnumeric() or uname[-1].isnumeric():
        print('No digits in first or last character!")
        parsed = False
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems with your validation such as `username.islower()` which asserts that the entire string be lower, not just a character in the string. These can be fixed by scanning the string such as `any(c.islower() for c in username)`. Then, you don't check all conditions each time you prompt for the username, you really aren't validating it at all.

Here's a single `while` loop that tracks failure by recording everything wrong with the input. It gives the user all of the bad news at once so that all problems can be fixed. And its more readable to boot.

```
while 1:
    username = input("Please enter user name: ")
    errs =  []
    if len(username) < 8 or len(username) > 15:
        errs.append("be between 8 and 15 characters long")
    if not username.isalnum():
        errs.append("only contain alphanumeric characters")
    if not any(c.lower() for c in username):
        errs.append("contain at least one lowercase character")
    if not any(c.upper() for c in username):
        errs.append("contain at least one uppercase character")
    if not any(c.isnumeric() for c in username):
        errs.append("contain at least one numeric character")
    if username[0].isnumeric():
        errs.append("not have digit as first character")
    if username[-1].isnumeric():
        errs.append("not have digit as last character")
    if errs:
        errs.insert(0, "Invalid. Username must...")
        print("\n  ..".join(errs))
    else:   
        break
```